# How to block traffic both in Google Analytics and on Server from a certain country?

Tags: google-analytics, spam-bots

I am getting traffic instances from Russia from fake referrers of Reddit, LifeHacker etc. I am not sure how did they get to my site. Is there anyway to block them from my site as well as from analytics?

Comment: the same issue I'm having . but why you guys marking this as duplicate @John Conde ?

Comment: This is not a dup. It's about  blocking the traffic in Analytics as well as on web server.

Comment: I know it's not dup.. but @John Conde marked this post as dup .. that's why I'm asking buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

This is affecting me at the moment. I solved it by using a Filter in Google Analytics

[image: block filter]

Comment: filters just ignores the traffics to track .. but how to prevent ?

Comment: Good to block traffic from Analytics but they are still making hits on site,aint they?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: @SharavnanKv I found this website, it gives out IPS to be blocked in .htaccess format https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx